# git merge commit details showing all lines in the file as deleted and then added

Tags: git

After merging (via squash) and resolving some conflicts, git starts showing in commit details that all lines have been removed from the file and then added back (vs. showing only modified lines to be deleted->added as normally modification action is tracked).

Should it be somehow explicitly marked on conflict resolution step, what has been changed?

Comment: I guess all the line endings have been changed, from LF to CRLF or in reverse.

Comment: Yes, it looks very much like line endings problem. Check your config for `autocrlf`

Comment: Ah, sure. I'm using VSCode on win machine with CLRF, and issue happened when i've applied correction in GitHub web editor, which supposedly replaced all end line characters.
So sticking to VSCode for conflict resolution fixed the issue.